# Formula for the ratio $\frac{\Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n + 1)}$ of two values of the Gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, beta-function

> Show that $$\frac{\Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n + 1)} = \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot \cdots (2 n - 3) (2 n - 1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot \cdots (2 n - 2) \cdot 2n} .$$

I have proved that $$\Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot \cdots (2 n - 3) (2 n - 1) \sqrt{\pi}}{2^n} \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad\Gamma(n+1) = n! ,$$
but when I divide, I am not able to proceed. Could you please help me?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $\Gamma(n+1/2)/\Gamma(n)$ really **is** a rational multiple of $\sqrt\pi$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: I did downvote. please use true format for your post to make it readable!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of formatting the post using MathJax. Please make sure it preserves the intended meaning. In particular, (1) the identity seems to be missing a factor of $\sqrt\pi$, and (2) the last equation in the original post was nonsensical; you might like to reinstate a corrected version.

Comment: The statement is false, as @Travis points out. Check it for $n=1$: $$\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(2)} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \neq \frac{1}{2}$$ Missing a $\sqrt{\pi}$ somewhere?

Comment: (Once you put that $\sqrt{\pi}$ back, what you have proven gives the result. Simply note that $$2^n n! = 2^n \prod_{k=1}^n k = \prod_{k=1}^n (2k) = 2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n-2)\cdot 2n$$ to conclude)

Answer (score 1):

You may

1. Define $f(n)$ as $\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)}$ and $g(n)$ as $\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$
2. Compute $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$ (via $\Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z)$) and $\frac{g(n+1)}{g(n)}$, then check they are equal
3. Compare $f(1)$ with $g(1)$ to derive that $f(n)$ is a constant multiple of $g(n)$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$.